# Storing output of called program in buffer

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to implement a remote shell. The server is supposed to read and execute both commands(cd, wait and exit) and programs that a user enters through the client. After executing the command or program the server is supposed to send the output back to the client.

I'm having some problems with sending the outputs back to the client, I would like to store the output in a buffer and then send it back using the write() function, but I don't know how to get the output of a system call or a program.

This is what I have thus far. The socket part is just a standard socket implementation that I have used.

Server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 9000
#define BUFSIZE 256
#define HOST "127.0.0.1"

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret, sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("Error opening socket");
    size_t sockaddrin_sz = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    memset((char*) &serv_addr,  0, sockaddrin_sz);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(HOST);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    ret = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sockaddrin_sz);
    if (ret < 0)
        error("ERROR while binding");
    ret = listen(sockfd, 5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    if (newsockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR on accept");
    while(1){
        memset(buffer, 0, BUFSIZE);
        ret = read(newsockfd, buffer, BUFSIZE -1);
// implement here: function to split buffer into command + arguments,
//function that calls corresponding system call or calls the program,
//STORE OUTPUT OF SYSTEM CALL OR PROGRAM IN BUFFER AND USE WRITE BELOW TO RETURN OUTPUT TO CLIENT.         
        if (ret < 0)
            error("ERROR reading");
        if (ret == 0)
            break;
        fprintf(stdout, "received: %s", buffer);
        fflush(stdout);
        ret = write(newsockfd, buffer, ret);
        if (ret < 0)
            error("ERROR writing to socket");

    }
    close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;



}
```

Client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 9000
#define HOST "127.0.0.1"
#define BUFSIZE 256

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(void){
    int ret, sockfd, portno;
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    struct sockaddr_in srv_addr;
    size_t sockaddrin_sz = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    srv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    srv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    srv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(HOST);

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("couldnt open socket");

    ret = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &srv_addr, sockaddrin_sz);

    if (ret < 0)
        error("ERROR couldnt connect to socket");

    size_t cmd_sz = BUFSIZE -1;
    char *cmd = buffer;

    while(1){
        printf("Please enter the message: ");

        ret = getline(&cmd, &cmd_sz, stdin);

        if (ret < 0)
            error("Couldnt get command from user");
        buffer[ret] = '/0';

        ret = write(sockfd, buffer, ret);

        if (ret < 0)
            error("Couldnt write to socket");

        if (!strcmp("exit\n", buffer))
            break;

        memset(buffer, 0, BUFSIZE);

        ret = read(sockfd, buffer, BUFSIZE - 1);

        if (ret < 0)
            error("ERROR couldnt read from socket");

        fprintf(stdout, "%s", buffer);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;

}
```

What I'd like to do now is write a function in the server that splits the input by the client to seperate the command from the arguments, then implement functions that call the corresponding system call based on the input and a function that executes the program that was entered by the client.

Now my problem is: How can I store the output of the system calls and the called programs in order to send that output back to the client?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble reading your server code - where are the commands being executed?

Comment: I haven't implemented those yet. I'd basically like to do the following and I'll add some comments in the code in a minute: After reading what the client sent into the buffer, I'd like to split that string in order to seperate the actual command from the arguments and then use a function to call the corresponding system call, e.g. chdir(). For a program, I'd create a child process with fork and then call execvp e.g. But since system call functions only return int and the program also doesn't necessarily return its output, I have no idea how to send the output back to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question, at the time of writing this answer, doesn't exactly specify the platform but from your examples I assume a POSIX operating system. In that case you either need to use a decent library (like libevent) or work with operating system primitives.

You will probably need at least the following primitives or their equivalents:

- `poll()` – Multiplex input and output in an event loop.
- `pipe()` – Create a communication channel.
- `fork()` – Create a new process.
- `close()` – Close a file descriptor.
- `dup()` – Reuse a file descriptor, useful for stdin/stdout redirection.
- `exec()` – Load an executable program into that process.

Example: Function that sets up a communication channel and runs an external command with input and output redirected to the communication channel whose other end is accessible from the main program.

```
static bool
start_subprocess(char *const command[], int *pid, int *infd, int *outfd)
{
    int p1[2], p2[2];

    if (!pid || !infd || !outfd)
            return false;

    if (pipe(p1) == -1)
            goto err_pipe1;
    if (pipe(p2) == -1)
            goto err_pipe2;
    if ((*pid = fork()) == -1)
            goto err_fork;

    if (*pid) {
            *infd = p1[1];
            *outfd = p2[0];
            close(p1[0]);
            close(p2[1]);
            return true;
    } else {
            dup2(p1[0], 0);
            dup2(p2[1], 1);
            close(p1[0]);
            close(p1[1]);
            close(p2[0]);
            close(p2[1]);
            execvp(*command, command);
            /* Subprocess error occured. */
            fprintf(stderr, "error running %s: %s", *command, strerror(errno));
            abort();
    }

err_fork:
    close(p2[1]);
    close(p2[0]);
err_pipe2:
    close(p1[1]);
    close(p1[0]);
err_pipe1:
    return false;
}
```

Source: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=netresolve.git;a=blob;f=backends/exec.c;hb=HEAD#l44

Answer (score 2):

The issue your facing resolves around inter-process communication.  The defacto method for having two processes communicate with one another is [by using pipes](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node9.html) (it's possible to use files, but that's impratical).

You're going to have to create a half-duplex pipe that writes from the executed system process to the server.  A pipe is a buffer, so you don't have to worry about creating a buffer - all you have to do is read the output from the pipe in the server in chunks and send each chunk to the client.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use named pipes with `mkfifo()`, and redirect the ouputs to the fifo, for example: `ls -l 1>./my_fifo 2>./my_fifo`. Here is a small example of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char * fifopath = "./my_fifo";
  char * command = "ls -l";
  char buf_cmd[2000];

  int myfifo = mkfifo(fifopath,0666);
  if(myfifo == -1) { printf("\nError mkfifo: %s",strerror(errno)); }

  pid_t pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0) {
    sprintf(buf_cmd,"%s 1>%s 2>%s",command,fifopath,fifopath);
    system(buf_cmd);
    printf("\nEnd of the child process.");
    return 0;
  }

  int fd = open(fifopath,O_RDONLY);
  if(fd <= 0) { printf("\nError open: %s",strerror(errno)); return 1; }

  int eof = 0;
  int ret;
  char buf[4097];
  while(!eof) {
    ret = read(fd,&buf,4096);
    buf[4096] = '\0';
    if(ret < 0) {
      printf("\nError read.");
    } else {
      if(ret == 0) eof = 1;
      else printf("%s",buf);
    }
  }
  close(fd);
  unlink(fifopath);

}
```

Comment: Why not use `pipe()` instead of `mkfifo()`?

Comment: You're right, pipe seems to be a better solution, when reading the link about pipe, i missed the section about redirecting stdin/out.